# How to view work item xml ids in azure ticket

Tags: python, xml, azure, azure-devops, workitem

I have an azure devops work item with some custom fields:

[image]

I can set some of these fields using the azure api python package, like so for 'RTCID':

```
jpo.path = "/fields/Custom.RTCID"
```

But when I try to set the targeted release, I can't find what the field path is for this variable, I've tried

```
jpo.path = "/fields/Custom.TargetedRelease"
```

But that results in an error.
I know my organization id, is there any way I can list all the variable path IDs in a ticket?

I tried going to [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitemtypes/Epic/fields](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/wit/workitemtypes/Epic/fields) to see all the fields, but ctrl+f searching for 'targeted' brings up no results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save the response time when calling a Azure DevOps REST API, many times it will not load the complete properties to the request body.

If you want to view more properties, you can try to use the parameter **`$expand`** to expand the complete properties.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitemtypes/{type}/fields?$expand=all&api-version=7.1-preview.3
```

In addition, you also can use the API "[**Work Items - Get Work Item**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-item?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)" to get a work item that is the work item type you require, and use the parameter **`$expand`** to expand all the fields.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?$expand=fields&api-version=7.1-preview.3
```

This also can list all the fields on the work item type.